How to fix npm error for node-sass npm error with node 20
I have upgraded my node from 12 to 20.
Now node-sass library is causing a problem.
Even if i am trying to install node-sass@9.0.0
Its internally trying to install 4.14.1 from @angular/cli module.
Npm info run node-sass@9.0.0 install node-modules/node-sass node scripts/install.js
npm ifor run node-sass@4.14.1 install node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass node scripts/install.js
node-sass@9.0.0 install {code:’ENOENT’,signal:undefined}
node-sass@4.14.1 install {code:’ENOENT’,signal:undefined}

Can someone please tell me why the behaviour is like this ?

node-sass is deprecated, stop using it

My project has dependency on it can’t remove it

You can almost certainly switch to sass instead, though, as they suggest.

Is sass is completely same as node-saa ? Or I have to change my code accordingly

Hard to say, we've no idea how you're using it. Unless you're using it directly somewhere, in a typical Angular CLI app it's a straight swap.
